# Proper Test for same proportions (multiple categories) on 2 groups, not normally distributed data, different sizes

Tags: sampling, chi-squared-test, proportion

I have trying to research the proper test for the following problem. I have 2 groups with different sizes n1 and n2. From each groups I am randomly sampling the same % of samples. (so say k*n1 and k*n2). the variables are categorical in nature. such variable is not normally distributed

```
In percentage, it will look like this:
Category    Draw_1    Draw_2
A           15%       13%
B           10%       25%
C           50%       40%
D           25%       22%
```

as you can see they sum to 100%. What I want to check is *equivalence testing*:

Are the multiple proportions statistically similar **as a whole**? meaning, are the two draws statistically comparable as in they are drawing approximately the same things?

I have looked at a bunch of tests (chisquared, t-test, pairs, etc) but none seem to fit the bill for this case. The closest one I think I have is the chi-squared test but I am not entirely sure that's the thing I need.

Comment: Are you trying to prove equivalence or difference?

Comment: I am trying to check for equivalence

Comment: Then you first need to decide on a tolerance for difference that will make the groups “practically” equivalent. // Please add to your original question that you want to do equivalence testing.

Comment: Yes true, but I was thinking on settling with a given p-value from the test I would have chosen